# Install osm2pgsql in a conda environment

Tags: installation, osm2pgsql, anaconda, conda

I have OpenStreetMap data and a database with the postgis extension, on a supercomputer (precisely Jean Zay, French cluster). In order to use JZ and install all the programs, packages etc I need on JZ, I use a conda environment.

I would like to populate my database using osm2pgsql (this is what I did on my local machine). Unfortunately, `conda install -c conda-forge osm2pgsql` shoots me the error `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels`.

I have tried anaconda instead of conda-forge, same result. Had no problem installing postgresql with this method. I haven't found any solution on SO nor on the manuals of conda and osm2pgsql. Given that this community uses osm2pgsql I think I have better chances at an answer than on StackOverflow.

How can I install osm2pgsql on a conda environment?

Comment: No-one has packaged it for conda https://anaconda.org/search?q=osm2pgsql (returns no results). Looks like you may have to build it from source unless you are able to run it in a Docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have looked around and haven't found a way to get osm2pgsql on the distant machine that would not require me asking for more rights from the superusers. So what I did is build it locally, pg_dump, send it and then pg_restore on the distant machine. Worked ok although not the most efficient way.